# Cancel all session variables with server command

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear session of all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317294/how-to-clear-session-of-all-users)

Is it possible to issue a command from a server (LAMP) that will destroy all current session variables? I want to be able to force all users off their session during periods of site maintenance. Is there an effective way of doing this or is this just silly?

Comment: How about deleting the session files?

Comment: you can clear that tmp file, check your php ini for the path

Comment: Is that how they are stored on the server? as temporary files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like Paul commented above: you can delete the session storage. This will terminate all current user sessions, session data will be lost.

```
$sessionFiles = glob(session_save_path().'/*');
foreach($sessionFiles as $file) {
    if(is_file($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$session_path = session_save_path();

shell_exec("rm " . $session_path . "/sess_*");
```

Comment: Shell_exec and rm commands with variables scare me!

Comment: I hear ya... There are more elegant solutions, like the one Michel Feldheim proposed.